# Starting a Tmux session from Github Action doesn't persist once the action completes

Tags: github-actions, tmux, github-actions-self-hosted-runners, github-actions-runners

I have a *self-hosted* Github Action with the main function of running a bash script to deploy a Django site. I cd into the directory, and then execute the bash script. This works fine, and I can see the print statements (`DEPLOY_FOLDER` AND `CONTAINER_NAME`) from the bash script in the Github Action GUI.

```
name: Deploy Workflow

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: [self-hosted, emts]
    steps:
    - name: CD and then deploy
      shell: bash
      run: |
        cd /export/home/scottc/
        ./deployserver.sh test test_deploy
```

HOWEVER, within my `deployserver.sh` script, I am starting a (detached) TMUX new session. I receive a notice that my job completed successfully, but when I check tmux sessions (`tmux ls`) after the job completes, I don't see any running.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $1
echo $2
DEPLOY_FOLDER=$1
CONTAINER_NAME=$2

tmux new -d -s $CONTAINER_NAME -- pipenv run python server_web/run_server.py
```

I have updated the `deployserver.sh` script to the below and found that a tmux session is actually being created, but must somehow get torn down when the job completes. I know this because after printing the `DEPLOY_FOLDER` and `CONTAINER_NAME`, I see `tmux ls` prints `test_deploy: 1 windows (created Thu May 18 11:00:49 2023) [80x24]` (while the job is still active but sleeping for 10 seconds). If I run `tmux ls` on the server during those 10 seconds, I do see an active window. However when the 10 seconds completes and the Github Action ends, the tmux session dissapears with it.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $1
echo $2
DEPLOY_FOLDER=$1
CONTAINER_NAME=$2

tmux new -d -s $CONTAINER_NAME -- pipenv run python server_web/run_server.py

sleep 3

tmux ls

sleep 10
```

**What do I need to change for the tmux session to persist after the github action completes?**

Comment: @pynexj what would this solve? I already know that it persists with `sleep 10` as I mentioned. And I don't want to the github job to be running for 9999 seconds, that defeats the purpose of using tmux. And I need it to work with the pipenv command as that is the most important part of the whole script, so switching to sleep doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 1):

By default, a shell session only lasts as long as it has an active window, a window only remains active as long as it has an active pane, and a pane only remains active until the command it is executing exits. When `run_server.py` exits, the initial pane is destroyed, taking the initial window with it and killing the session.

One way to keep it alive is to set the `remain-on-exit` option on the pane. (With no `-t` option, `set-option` affects the currently active pane. With only one server, one session, one window, and one pane, that happens to be the one running your command.)

```
tmux new -d ...
tmux set-option -p remain-on-exit
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that run_server.py isn't supposed to ever "exit" or "complete". It stays running indefinitely (until server crashes or is cancelled manually). Hence the reason to have it running in a tmux windows so that once the github job completes, the tmux windows stays running to serve the webpage.

Comment: If I run the same `deployserver.sh` script manually (not with github action), then the detached tmux shell opens, and stays running in the background. It's only when launching the same script from a github action that the window is destroyed when the job completes (i.e. `tmux new ...` command runs, not the `run_server.py` "finishing").

When I try adding the `set-option...` line, I receive `tmux: unknown option -- p
usage: set-option [-aFgosquw] [-t target-window] option [value]`. I tried `tmux set-option remain-on-exit` but still having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** Instead of running
`./deployserver.sh test test_deploy`
use `RUNNER_TRACKING_ID="" && (./deploysensei.sh test test_deploy)`

The problem was evident in the "Complete Job" logs on Github:

```
Cleaning up orphan processes
Terminate orphan process: pid (1050875) (tmux: server)
Terminate orphan process: pid (1050876) (bash)
Terminate orphan process: pid (1051071) (pipenv)
Terminate orphan process: pid (1051075) (python)
```

I can see that the action was terminating orphan processes, including tmux. When you reassign the Github env variable `RUNNER_TRACKING_ID`, then during the teardown process it doesn't terminate the existing processes.

More details [here](https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/598).